# Instagram 429 Error during SEO Scanning

Tags: seo, social-media, social-sharing-buttons, instagram

All pages (14000+, due to master layout) have a link to the Instagram brand page, and for some reason the SEO scanning tool is citing a 429 error for only one of the pages. I'm thinking it's rate limiting the scanning bot, and wanted to see if adding a no-follow would solve that or not?

Comment: If you have the same link on every page, an SEO scanner shouldn't fetch it more than once per crawl, even if multiple pages link to it. What SEO scanning tool are you using? It sounds like it has a bug.

Answer (score 2):

429 error fires if Instagram detects (or guess to detect) suspicial (automated) activities on account. I think your crawler tries to access Instagram pages through their external links.

Try to exclude Instagram links from crawling. I would in any case nofollow them.